# Format hours, minutes and seconds with moment.js

Tags: momentjs

I get this value from my backend service: `171054`. It represents `hh:mm:ss`. But when I use the formatting options from the docs it gives me back `00:00:00`.

Things I've tried:

```js
moment('171054').format('hh-mm-ss')
moment('171054').format('HH-mm-ss')
moment('171054').format('HH-MM-SS')
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You are confusing [format](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) option with parsing option. Since your input string is not in ISO 8601 format, you have to [specify format when parsing](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/).

Here a working example for your use case:

```js
var mom = moment('171054', 'HHmmss');
console.log(mom.format());
console.log(mom.format('HH:mm:ss'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if momentjs can read that as date since there is no identifier. I would suggest changing the value for example you have 171054, get each 2 digits since you sure that this is represent as hh:mm:ss then add identifier between then like ":" or "-" then try us momentjs formatting again.