# Parsing paypal date time string using moment

Tags: javascript, paypal, momentjs

Paypal produces date string in IPN as HH:MM:SS Mmm DD, YYYY PDT
I am from a different timezone and I need to convert this string to current timezone from PDT and display a date time.

Reference: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/

```
var date = moment("16:23:42 Sep 27, 2018 PDT").format('HH:MM:SS MMM DD, YYYY zzz');
console.log(date)
//The out put of above code was: 04:09:00 Sep 28, 2018
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: What is the meaning of `PDT` in this context? Does it stand for _Payment Data Transfer_ or does it mean _Pacific Daylight Time_? Anyway you have to use [`moment(String, String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) to parse your input (something related [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40255825/4131048))