# How to get right format in moment js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

i need to convert input value: ":2" to 'HH:mm' format.
":2" it should be converted to "00:20". All this process should be done with moment.js

```js
let timeString = ":2";
const time = document.getElementById('time');

time.innerHTML = moment(timeString).format('HH:mm');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.js"></script>
<span id="time"></span>
```

I didn't put input, because my problem is to get or convert correct format.

Comment: How is `:2` supposed to be 20? You need to format that to something that makes sense first, moment won't know you meant 00:20 (I just tried to be sure). You need to change that to `00:20` yourself first.

Comment: Maybe it is possible to get `_i` value (in this case :2) and check it with if statement, then convert only string like `split` function to get only number. But i have no idea how to get `_i` value.

Comment: Totally agree with Dominic, moreover please do not use `_i` and other [internal variables](http://momentjs.com/guides/#/lib-concepts/internal-properties/), and do not confuse between parsing and formatting (an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40255825/4131048))

Comment: But this still doesn't resolve my problem. could i use: `moment(':2').toISOstring()` ?

Comment: @Nienormalny_ it is unclear what you're trying to achieve. What results you expect for the following `timeString` inputs: `":3"`, `":1.5"`, `":21"` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated before, you will have to convert the input yourself before passing it to momentjs - the following could work for you, depending on what the result for other values should be. I assumed:

- ":3" -> "00:30",
- ":21" -> "00:21",
- "2:2" -> "02:20"

```js
    let timeString = ":2";
    const hours = timeString.split(":")[0] || "00";
    let minutes = timeString.split(":")[1];

    if (minutes.length === 1) {
        minutes = minutes * 10;
    }

    const parsedTime = hours + ":" + minutes;

    const time = document.getElementById('time');
    time.innerHTML = moment(parsedTime, "HH:mm").format("HH:mm");
```

Comment: Thanks! That was solution :) I found it already. And it is a bit diferent as yours but the Idea was same! Will be helpfull for another devs :)